# PowerShell retrieve two directories of last level

Tags: powershell

I have this variable:

```
$sourcePath ="D:\test1\test2\test3\test4"
```

I want to retrive `"\test3\test4"`

I've tried this, but it's not working:

```
"\Split-Path (Split-Path $sourcePath -Parent) \ -Leaf Split-Path $sourcePath -Leaf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run a cmdlet inside of double quotes, you will need to use a subexpression `$()` otherwise it won't be evaluated.

```
"\$(Split-Path (Split-Path $sourcePath -Parent) -Leaf)\$(Split-Path $sourcePath -Leaf)"
```

As an alternative you could use `Get-Item`'s parent property to retrieve the level you want and then use `-replace` to remove it.

```
$sourcePath ="D:\test1\test2\test3\test4"
$ParentParent = (Get-Item $sourcePath).Parent.Parent.FullName
$regex = [regex]::escape($ParentParent)
$sourcePath -replace $regex,""
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
$sourcePath ="D:\test1\test2\test3\test4"
"\" + (($sourcePath -split "\\")[-2..-1] -join "\")
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
$sourcePath ="D:\test1\test2\test3\test4"
$Root2Level=[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($sourcePath))
$sourcePath.Replace($Root2Level, '')
```